# Move element inside a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to change the position of a single element in a list. Example: I start with:

```
{a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

I want to move the `a` before the `d` to get:

```
{b,c,a,d,e,f}
```

How would I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
data = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
Permute[data, {3, 1, 2}]
```

or

```
Permute[data, Cycles[{{1, 3, 2}}]]
```

Both give

> ```
> {b, c, a, d, e, f}
> ```

#### Edit

It occurred to me that it would be good to be able to move an element to a lower position in the list as well as a higher one. Together the following two functions give both capabilities.

Upward movement -- move an element at position `m` to position `n`, where `m < n`:

```
moveElementUp[data_List, m_Integer /; m > 0, n__Integer /; n > 0] /; m < n :=
  Permute[data, Join[Range[m - 1], {n}, Range[m, n - 1]]]

moveElementUp[data, 1, 3]
```

> ```
> {b, c, a, d, e, f}
> ```

```
moveElementUp[data, 2, 5]
```

> ```
> {a, c, d, e, b, f}
> ```

```
moveElementUp[data, 1, 6]
```

> ```
> {b, c, d, e, f, a}
> ```

Downward movement -- move an element at position `m` to position `n`, where `m > n`:

```
moveElementDown[data_List, m_Integer /; m > 0, n__Integer /; n > 0] /; m > n :=
  Permute[data, Join[Range[n - 1], 1 + Range[n, m - 1], {n}]]

moveElementDown[data, 3, 1]
```

> ```
> {c, a, b, d, e, f}
> ```

```
moveElementDown[data, 5, 3]
```

> ```
> {a, b, e, c, d, f}
> ```

```
moveElementDown[data, 6, 1]
```

> ```
> {f, a, b, c, d, e}
> ```

#### Note

Although I found it interesting to attack this problem with permutations, I suspect there is a better solution.

Answer (score 6):

The following answer is effectively equivalent to m_goldberg's answer, except that the distinction between the two directions of movement has been eliminated:

```
moveElement[l_List, m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] :=
   Module[{idx}, 
                idx = Range @@ Sort[{m, n}];
                ReplacePart[l, Thread[idx -> l[[RotateLeft[idx, Sign[n - m]]]]]]]
```

Both `moveElementUp[]` and `moveElementDown[]` in his answer can be replaced with this unified function.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not the most elegant way but...

```
swap[list_, from_, to_] := 
 Module[{ele = list[[from]], modlist = list}, 
  modlist[[from]] = Sequence[]; modlist = Insert[modlist, ele, to];
  modlist]

swap[list, 1, 3]
```

> `{b, c, a, d, e, f}`

If you always want the moving element in front of `d`...

```
swap[list, 1, FirstPosition[list, d] - 1]
```

Note, in 10.2 you can use `Nothing` instead of `Sequence[]`.

Or, if you insist on using patterns...

```
from = 1;
to = 3;
list /. {a___, list[[from]], b___, list[[to + 1]], c___} :> {a, b, 
 list[[from]], list[[to + 1]], c}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you could just

```
moveElement[l_, from_, to_] := Insert[Delete[l, from], l[[from]], to]
```

Works up and down.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
SubsetMap[RotateLeft, list, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> {b, c, a, d, e, f}

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[move]
move[lst_, from_, to_] :=  Module[{a = lst, p = Sort[{from, to}]}, 
  a[[p[[1]] ;; p[[2]]]] =  RotateRight[a[[p[[1]] ;; p[[2]]]], to - from]; a]

move[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, 1, 3]
```

> {b, c, a, d, e, f}

```
move[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, 3, 1]
```

> {c, a, b, d, e, f}