# Move part of expression

Tags: expression-manipulation

What is the best way to take a part of an expression and put it somewhere else in the same expression? Essentially I need to combine a `Extract`, `Delete` and `Insert` atomically, that is, handle corner cases where the deletion might cause a shift of the position where I want to insert to, or similar problems.

Comment: Can you give an example expression and your intended outcome?

Comment: this sounds like [Move element inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88887/125)?

Comment: Could you clarify: when you move the element in position i to position j do the relative positions of other elements stay fixed? Or do you want to move the element in  position j to position i (swap elements in ith and jth positions)?

Answer (score 1):

If the parts you want to move are at the same level, you can use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part):

```
list = Range[10];

list[[{3, 7}]] = list[[{7, 3}]];
list
```

> {1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 8, 9, 10}

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[changePos]
changePos = Insert[Delete[#, #2], #[[#2]], {#3}] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
changePos[CharacterRange["a", "k"], 7, 3]
```

> {"a", "b", "g", "c", "d", "e", "f", "h", "i", "j", "k"}

```
changePos[CharacterRange["a", "k"], 3, 7]
```

> {"a", "b", "d", "e", "f", "g", "c", "h", "i", "j", "k"}