# reducing matrix size by linear operations on rows and columns

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Suppose that I have the following matrix:

```
matrix = Table[i+j, {i, 5}, {j, 0, 4}];
```

which generates

[image]

I like to write a `Mathematica` function such as `mm[matrix_]` to conduct linear operations using rows and columns. For example, summing 1st and 4th columns and summing 2nd row with 5th row. The resulting function should be obtained using `mm[matrix_]`. The position of the new column and row is not important for my purpose.

The output should be:

```
{{2  3  5  5},
 {9 11 20 15},
 {4  5  9  7},
 {5  6 11  8}}
```

Thanks.

Tugrul

Comment: matrix[[2]] + matrix[[5]] sums the second and fifth rows. You might want to look at the instruction Part[ ] which is what is being used by the double brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Transpose @ Fold[Module[{m = Transpose@#, x = #2}, 
     ReplacePart[m, Join[#[[1]] -> Plus @@ m[[#]] & /@ x, 
      {Alternatives @@ Flatten[x[[All, 2 ;;]]] -> Sequence[]}]]] &, #, {##2}] &;

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ f[matrix, {{2, 5}}, {{4, 1}}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  2 & 3 & 5 & 5 \\
>  9 & 11 & 20 & 15 \\
>  4 & 5 & 9 & 7 \\
>  5 & 6 & 11 & 8 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
matrix2 = Partition[Range[81], 9]; 
TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ f[matrix2, {{2, 5, 1}, {3, 4}}, {{4, 1, 5}, {7, 8, 9}}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  35 & 62 & 213 & 143 & 591 \\
>  25 & 43 & 147 & 97 & 399 \\
>  15 & 24 & 81 & 51 & 207 \\
>  16 & 25 & 84 & 52 & 210 \\
>  17 & 26 & 87 & 53 & 213 \\
>  18 & 27 & 90 & 54 & 216 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Also:

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2 = Module[{m = #}, m[[#2[[1]]]] += m[[#2[[2]]]]; 
    m[[All, #3[[1]]]] += m[[All, #3[[2]]]]; 
    Drop[m, {#2[[2]]}, {#3[[2]]}]] &;

f2[matrix, {2, 5}, {4, 1}] == f[matrix, {{2, 5}, {4, 1}}]
```

> True

Comment: Yes, it works fine. Can we extend your Code to do operations on more than 2 columns and more than 2 rows. My example was for illustrative purposes, and in reality I have a matrix of 60 by 60, and need to reduce its dimension to 25 by 25. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, I updated `f` to work with arbitrary number of rows and columns.

Comment: I noticed that with your `Code` above, I can only do isolated single  operation such as, say, combining 3 rows and 3 columns (a single operation). My problem goes beyond this because I wanted to combine groups of rows at the same time: i.e., combine rows: 1,3,4 as one group, and combine rows: 2,4 as another group at the same time not sequentially. This means that `f[matrix, {{1,3,4}, {2,4}}, {{1,3,4},{2,4}}]` should be in this form (?), but this does not work. Basically, I wanted to do all the operations involved with one command, not several commands.

Comment: @Tugrul, updated `f` to take lists of lists of rows (and columns) to be combined.

Comment: It works perfect...Thank you so much.

Comment: I am not sure if writing you from here is proper. I wanted to ask you something that is very much related to your answer above. The above answer solved my problem. BUT I was wondering if you can also show me how one can simply exchange the location of a row, say, moving 1st row to 4th row and at the same time moving 1st column to 4th column without making any arithmetical calculations. Simply moving rows and columns by keeping the integrity of the matrix. Thank you very much in advance. Tugrul

Comment: @Tugrul, does `matrix[[{1,4}]]=matrix[[{4,1}}]; matrix[[All, {1,4}]]=matrix[[All, {4,1}]]` work?

Comment: No. It does not work. Maybe I inputted wrongly. I used your `f` function above. I tried also as you suggested, none of them works. In fact, the question you answered earlier does the thing but it adds two rows or columns. Now I simply want to change the places of row 1 and column 1 to a location say row 4 and column 4. Row 1 moves to row 4, column 1 moves to column 4. The rest of the matrix remains the same. Tugrul

Comment: Tugrul,  if the row (or column) to be moved is not necessarily one of the rows (columns) that appear in the arguments of `f`, then it is probably a good idea to post as a new question. If it is, than you can re-shuffle the list of rows (say, `{2,3,4}`)  to be combined so that the target position (say, 4) appears first (that is, use `{4,2,3}`). Similarly for the list of of columns to be combined.

Comment: After applying your function `f`, I obtain a matrix, say, `M`. But then, given `M` I want to rearrange rows and columns of `M` without any mathematical operations. Simply change the locations of some rows and columns. Should I post a new question for this? If so, I will do it. Thanks.

Comment: Tugrul if you want to swap rows i and j, using `matrix[[{i,j}]] =matrix[{j,i}]]` should work (for columns `matrix[[All, {i,j}]]=matrix[[All,{j,i}}]]`) . If you want to mow row i to position j without changing the relative order of other rows it is a bit more involved.

Comment: Since my matrix is a symmetric one, I want to keep it as symmetric as to the names of columns and rows. I will post a new question because it is a bit complicated. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Tugrul, for the second case [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88887/125) may be useful.

Comment: Sorry I could not reply you earlier because I was out of country. I looked at the link you sent me and I have the same problem but I have a matrix instead of a list. As you suggested, I prepared a question to address my problem and now I will post it. Thanks again for your kind information.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about matrix functions. Something like:

```
r2p5[matrix_]:= matrix[[2]] + matrix[[5]]
```

yields the sum of rows 2 and 5 of whatever matrix you feed it.

All `r2p5[something]` does is:

Evaluates `something`.

Takes the result of that and substitutes it for `matrix` in the expression `matrix[[2]] + matrix[[5]]`

Evaluates the resulting expression.

Comment: My question was not completely clear and has some missing information. Suppose I have 5 by 5 matrix. Sum 2nd and 5th columns and create a new column 'c25' and do the same sum on row and create a new row 'r25'. By doing this operation we reduce the size of the original matrix to 4 by 4. I wanted to do the entire operation by a matrix function and get the final reduced matrix of 4 by 4, which is the output form in my question.

Comment: You said above you knew how to do this, but not in a function. But if you know how to do it, you know how to do it in a function, it's the same.