# Changing the position of rows and columns in a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have the following self-explanatory question.

`https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsyHs3E_aioxhipb3wSPSX_heN-t`

[image]

As seen from the above matrices, I start with the "original" matrix, which is a symmetric matrix, meaning that first row and first column represent the same variable, say `X`, and 2nd row and 2nd column represent the variable `Y`, following `Z, W, V`. I first want to move 2nd row in the "original" matrix to 4th row. This operation is shown in the matrix denoted by `r24`. After this operation, I want to do the same operation on the same columns, meaning that I want to move 2nd column to 4th column as shown in `c24`. All of these operations are shown with the colored text. The resulting final matrix, which I aim to create, `c24`, should be symmetric with respect to the variable names. It means that the final matrix has the ordered variable names as `X, Z, W, Y, V` in columns and rows. In fact, if the above two operations are done correctly, the order of the variables in rows and columns will remain identical.

I like to do all the operations using a Mathematica function such as `f[original, 2, 4]` to create the final matrix `c24`.

Thank you all.

Comment: closely related/ possible duplicate: [Move element inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88887/125)

Comment: FWIW: your matrix is called a Hankel matrix. `HankelMatrix[Range[5], Range[5, 9]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `Part` and `Set`:

```
f[A_?SquareMatrixQ, i_Integer, j_Integer] := Module[{p, idx},
 idx = Range[i, j, Sign[j - i]];
 p = Range[1, Length[A]];
 p[[idx]] = RotateLeft[idx];
 A[[p, p]]
 ]

A = Outer[Plus, Range[5], Range[0, 4]];
A // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
>  3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
>  4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
>  5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
B = f[A,2,4];
B // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  1 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 5 \\
>  3 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 7 \\
>  4 & 6 & 7 & 5 & 8 \\
>  2 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 6 \\
>  5 & 7 & 8 & 6 & 9 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Your answer is very good, with one slight change. When you move the 2nd row to 4th row, the order of the rows should remain unchanged. It means that when you move the 2nd row, the 3rd and 4th rows should just be moved up without changing the order. Of course the same applies to the column movements. This is important for my purpose and that is why I gave a name for rows and columns. Thank you very much for your very quick answer.

Comment: @TugrulTemel I see. Is this better now? I am not sure if the case $i>j$ is handled as you expect.

Comment: Excellent...that is what I aim to achieve. Really, thank you so much for your prompt answer. regards, Tugrul

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: You didn't reply, but anyway: `q = Range[i, j, Sign[j - i]]; p = RotateLeft[q];`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry, I've been out tonight. This won't happen again, I promise ;) Thank you, that is indeed simpler. I took the freedom to incorporate that into my solution (in an updated version with more performance).

Answer (score 6):

to move a row from $i$ to $j$:

```
rowmove[A_?MatrixQ, i_Integer, j_Integer] := Insert[Delete[A, i], A[[i]], j]
```

to move a column from $i$ to $j$:

```
colmove[A_?MatrixQ, i_Integer, j_Integer] := Transpose@rowmove[Transpose[A], i, j]
```

both at the same time:

```
move[A_?MatrixQ, i_Integer, j_Integer] := colmove[rowmove[A, i, j], i, j]
```

Comment: Clean solution, copying it...

Comment: Here is somewhat simplified version of your solution `f[A_?MatrixQ, i_Integer, 
  j_Integer] := (B = Insert[Delete[A, i], A[[i]], j]; 
  Insert[Delete[Transpose@B, i], B[[All, i]], j])` or this one `g[A_?MatrixQ, i_Integer, 
  j_Integer] := (B = Transpose@Insert[Delete[A, i], A[[i]], j]; 
  Transpose@Insert[Delete[B, i], B[[i]], j])`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci I don't think it's a good idea to use global variables like `B` in a function definition. Instead, I'd use `With` or `Module` to make the variable local.

Answer (score 5):

Define the indices that you want to interchange in a list $ind$ and then you can index into the array $a$ directly.

```
a = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
     {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}; 
ind = {1, 3, 4, 2, 5};
a[[ind, ind]]
```

If you don't want to specify the index array each time, Roman points out that you can build a simple function to do it:

```
indexlist[n_, i_, j_] := Insert[Delete[Range[n], i], i, j]
```

So to get the above you would specify

```
ind = indexlist[5,2,4]
```

Comment: You can get the index list `ind` with `indexlist[n_, i_, j_] := Insert[Delete[Range[n], i], i, j]`. In this case, `indexlist[5, 2, 4]` will give `{1, 3, 4, 2, 5}`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
om = HankelMatrix[Range[5], Range[5, 9]];

om // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Move 2nd row of `om` to 4th row

```
rm = SubsetMap[RotateLeft, om, {2, 3, 4}];

rm // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Move 2nd column of `rm` to 4th column

```
cm = Query[All, SubsetMap[RotateLeft, #, {2, 3, 4}] &] @ rm;

MapAt[Style[#, Bold]&, {{4, All}, {All, 4}}] @ cm // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**Addendum**

To swap rows (instead of moving) we omit the middle `3`:

```
SubsetMap[RotateLeft, om, {2, 4}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
hm = HankelMatrix[Range[5], Range[5, 9]];

MatrixForm@hm
```

[image]

Using `Permute` and `Cycle` to determine the ordering:

```
ord = Permute[Range[5], Cycles[{{4, 3, 2}}]]

(*{1, 3, 4, 2, 5}*)
```

Applying the ordering to move 2nd row of `hm` to 4th row:

```
rm = hm[[ord]];

MapAt[Style[#, Bold, Red] &, {{4, All}, {All, 2}}]@rm // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Applying the ordering to move 2nd column of `rm` to 4th column:

```
cm = (Transpose@rm)[[ord]];

MapAt[Style[#, Bold, Darker@Blue] &, {{4, All}, {All, 4}}]@cm // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
f[A_?MatrixQ, i_Integer, j_Integer] := With[{B = Transpose@Insert[Delete[A, i], A[[i]], j]}, 
  Transpose@Insert[Delete[B, i], B[[i]], j]]
f[A, 2, 4] // MatrixForm
```