# What is the best way to rearrange the following list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list

```
\[ScriptL]0 = 4
 mtablep = Riffle[Range[0, -\[ScriptL]0, -1], Range[\[ScriptL]0]]
```

which produces the following:

```
 {0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4}
```

I want to have my list as:

```
 {0, 1, -1, -2, 2, 3, -3, -4, 4}
```

Could you help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move element inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88887/move-element-inside-a-list)

Comment: Two brief demonstrations from the previous link: `(mtablep // moveElementUp[#, 4, 5] &) // moveElementUp[#, 8, 9] &` and also `moveElement[moveElement[mtablep, 4, 5], 8, 9]` give as output `{0, 1, -1, -2, 2, 3, -3, -4, 4}`

Comment: Can you give a rule for your order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for some reason, you can't generate them in the correct order as @qbg suggested, you could always use `Sort` with a custom sorting function afterwards.

```
\[ScriptL]0 = 4;
mtablep = Riffle[Range[0, -\[ScriptL]0, -1], Range[\[ScriptL]0]];
sortfunc = Which[
  Abs[#2] == Abs[#1] \[And] EvenQ[#1],
  RealSign[#2 - #1],
  Abs[#2] == Abs[#1] \[And] OddQ[#1],
  RealSign[#1 - #2],
  True,
  RealSign[Abs[#2] - Abs[#1]]
] &;
Sort[mtablep, sortfunc]
```

> {0,1,-1,-2,2,3,-3,-4,4}

Basically, this checks to see if the absolute values are the same. If they are, put the negative one first if it's even and second if it's odd (at least I presume that's the rule you're using). If the absolute values are not the same, then sort by absolute value.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can just generate the list in the right order to start with? Assuming this is your rule:

```
 In[1]:= \[ScriptL]0 = 4;
 In[2]:= Flatten@{0, Table[If[Mod[x, 2] == 0, -1, 1]*{x, -x}, {x, \[ScriptL]0}]}
Out[2]:= {0, 1, -1, -2, 2, 3, -3, -4, 4}
```